# Finding common denominator of a polynomial

Tags: calculus, limits

I am solving a limit and am stuck with finding the common denominator. This is the limit that I have:

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \left( \frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{3}{1-x^3} \right)$$

Since $x \to 1$, the limit is $\frac{1}0 - \frac{3}0$ - or $\infty - \infty$.

So, I think the next thing I need to do is find the common denominator and continue from there on.

I would very much appreciate an answer. Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: $1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)$. Therefore a common denominator can be $1-x^3$. The sum can be written as $\frac{1+x+x^2-3}{1-x^3}$.

Comment: $$x^2+x-2$$ can be factorized

Comment: Yes Ginna, thank you. I got your result, but what can I factor next?

Comment: The numerator became $x^2+x-2=(x-1)(x+2)$. Therefore the fraction is equal to $\frac{x+2}{1+x+x^2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^3}=\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{(1-x)(x^2+x+1)}=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(1-\frac{3}{x^2+x+1}\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{x^2+x-2}{x^2+x+1}\right)=\frac{1}{1-x}\left(\frac{(x-1)(x+2)}{x^2+x+1}\right)=\frac{-(x+2)}{x^2+x+1}$$

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was the most straightforward for me to understand.

Comment: @HarveyRoss I'm glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

This might help you.

$$1-x^3= (1-x)(1+x+x^2)$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Now I get 1+x+x^2-3/(1-x)^3. What can I factor out next?

Comment: your numerator become $x+x^2-2=(x-1)((x+2)$ now you can cancelled $(x-1)$ from both numerator and denominator.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\;1-x^3=(1-x)(1+x+x^2)\,$, then by partial fraction decomposition:

$$
\frac{1}{1-x^3} = \frac{1}{3}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}+\frac{x+2}{1+x+x^2}\right)
$$

It follows that:

$$\require{cancel}
\frac{1}{1-x} - \frac{3}{1-x^3} = \cancel{\frac{1}{1-x}} - \left(\cancel{\frac{1}{1-x}} + \frac{x+2}{1+x+x^2}\right) = - \,\frac{x+2}{1+x+x^2}
$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: note that $$1-x^3=- \left( -1+x \right)  \left( {x}^{2}+x+1 \right) $$
and $$\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^3}=-{\frac {x+2}{{x}^{2}+x+1}}$$
$$\frac{1}{1-x}-\frac{3}{1-x^3}=\frac{-x^3+3x-2}{(1-x)(1-x^3}=\frac{-(x+2)(x-1)^2}{(1-x)(1-x^3)}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. How did you get - (x+2)?